# How to display distinct rows from single column without using DISTINCT keyword and count() function?

Tags: database-theory, databases

How to display distinct rows from single column without using DISTINCT keyword and [having count(*) > 1 ] ?  My question is can we do this using sub-queries or co-related sub query ?
If yes how we can do this ?

Please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be, essentially, a programming question, which would be [off-topic, here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Hi,I need SQL Query for that. I don't need any programming for this question. Can we write SQL Query for this ?

Comment: An SQL query is a program.